# Instagram API Unauthorized token although it is a live token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, instagram, instagram-api

I am building an app with Instagram's API where I can search photos by tags.

Unfortunately I am getting this error although I do have the live token (not the sandbox one):

> 400: This request requires scope=public_content, but this access token is not authorized with this scope. The user must re-authorize your application with scope=public_content to be granted this permissions.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. To help you, it is important, your problem can be understood. To help us understand your problem it is usually helpful, to post a minimal, complete and verifiable example of your code, that leads to your error. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more details on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

you probably have you app in live mode but with just `basic` permission.

`basic` permission is only good for getting your own photos via API.

To access other user's content and search you need to login with scope `public_content` and also get that approved by Instagram for `public_content` permission (which is not very easy btw, try it)